# Build Failed after adding the flutter_paypal SDK?

Tags: flutter, paypal, flutter-dependencies, paypal-rest-sdk

After adding the [flutter_paypal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paypal) SDK to my project, when I run the app, I am getting the following error:

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\MyApplication\Application\application\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 32
  ...
}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
     Dependency: androidx.webkit:webkit:1.5.0.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\MyPc\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1e17c3cecd51956dd096ba6a3522bf2f\webkit-1.5.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

I updated the `compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion` to `compileSdkVersion 32` in `build.gradle` and run the app which then gives the following error:

```
D:\MyApplication\Application\application\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:webview_flutter_android] D:\MyApplication\Application\application\build\webview_flutter_android\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

My `Manifest.xml` file has no such entry `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion` then why are these errors? And how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 16 //This place will be 19 or higher
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```